# Cannot populate email field using JavaScript from local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files test.html and test2.html I am able to save the value of the forms but cannot fill the input field in test2.html form.

Test.html

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
  function store(){
     var inputEmail= document.getElementById("email");

     localStorage.setItem("email", inputEmail.value);
    }
</script>
<form action="test2.html" class="form-login"  method="post" /> 
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" required="" placeholder="Email" />

<button onclick="store()" type="button">StoreEmail</button>
```

Test2.html

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function get(){

         var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("email");

         document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = storedValue;
         document.getElementById("email").value = storedValue;

        }
    </script>
    <p id="email">qqqqqq</p>
    <form action="" class="form-login"  method="post" /> 
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />

<button onclick="get()" type="button">getEmail</button>
```

When I click on getEmail button the paragraph changes but the Email input field doesn't change with the value. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id of every DOM node is supposed to be unique within the entire DOM

document.getElementById returns always the first matched dom node